# How to calculate percentage in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not understanding, why am I getting 0.01% instead 100%, please advise

This is my query:

```
SELECT Total_Price,concat(round(total_price/(SUM(total_price)*100),2),'%') AS percentage
FROM Sales
WHERE Department IN ('SPORT','MUSIC')
AND DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-30'
```

Thanks

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  You have an aggregation, but no `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySQL is very permissive about agregation. You can do lot of bad query with MySQL and it still work. Have a look on this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/531d0e/2

Comment: @Genu A demonstration in sucking eggs would also be useful if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the total as a subquery...

```
select t1.total_price, (t1.total_price/t2.grand_total)*100 as pc
from MyTable t1
inner join
(
select sum(tx.total_price) as grand_total
from MyTable tx
AND tx.DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-30'
) t2
on 1=1
WHERE Department IN ('SPORT','MUSIC')
AND DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-30'
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND tx.DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-30' ) t2 on 1=1 WHERE Department I' at line 7". can u pls advise?

Comment: solved it by:SELECT Total_Price,concat(round(total_price/(SUM(total_price))*100,2),'%') AS percentage
FROM Sales
WHERE Department IN ('SPORT','MUSIC')
AND DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-30';